# Using the lens equation to make a camera out of an old projector lens

Tags: focal-length, old-lenses

Given a 14" (~355mm) projector lens, does the film plane go a little more than 14" behind the center of the lens? I'm puzzled by the use of the canonical lens equation for long object distances, as it puts the image distance arbitrarily close to the lens, when all  the DIY cameras I've seen pictures of show a considerable lens-to-film-plane distance. I'm quite sure I'm missing something simple here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The film plane will be located, for objects at infinity, 14 inches from the rear nodal of the lens. If a simple lens is involved, we measure from its center. A complex lens has a forward and a rear nodal plane. We will likely not know their locations without running a complex test. That being said, use the lens as a burring glass. In other words, project a focused image of the sun onto a white paper screen.
focus this image of the sun by adjusting lens to screen distance. When a tiny image of the sun is achieved, measure distance screen to a point 14 inches rearward. Likely this will fall somewhere on the lens barre. Mark this point, it is the location of the rear nodal.

Comment: The geometry of what you describe is a little uncertain to me. When all is set, there is a piece of paper with an image of the sun, and the lens some distance from the paper. Going 'rearwards' is going to go away from the lens, so how can it be on the barrel?

Comment: The rear nodal location can fall somewhere within the lens Berrell or in air forward or reward of the barrel. Likely for a projection lens, it will fall near the center of the barrel.  If a 14-inch projection is imaging an object at infinity, the image forms 14 inches downstream of the rear nodal.

Comment: Lenses act like a pinhole the focal distance from the focal plane.  Being actually a lens and not a pinhole they distort light to function and distort this distance when they do. This new nodal point can often be completely outside the lens.  See for example a camera with a 28mm lens and a longer distance from film/sensor to the lens.  On cameras the figure you're looking for would be called the film-flange distance.